# Why does ModelName.objects.using('db').filter(...) in django with mongodb return a not iterable error?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

Why does: 
`v = Word.objects.using('mongodata').filter(word = word, title=title)[0]`

return the error `TypeError 'Exact' object is not iterable`?

Full Traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/AddToModels.py", line 96, in addWord
    v = Word.objects.using('mongodata').filter(word = word, title=tit)[0]#.filter(__raw__={"title":tit})#.filter(word = word)
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 177, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 141, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 966, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py", line 375, in results_iter
    results = self.build_query(fields).fetch(
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py", line 481, in build_query
    query.add_filters(self.query.where)
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongodb_engine/compiler.py", line 184, in add_filters
    field, lookup_type, value = self._decode_child(child)
  File "/home/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.py", line 194, in _decode_child
    constraint, lookup_type, annotation, value = child
TypeError: 'Exact' object is not iterable
```

Same issue with get.

```
type(v) = <class 'django_mongodb_engine.contrib.MongoDBQuerySet'>
```

Works fine if I use .all()

Setup:

- MongoDb 2.4.6
- Django 1.7
- Routers, relational db for auth and user, non rel for data

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from the line you have posted? Please share the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AamirAdnan added full traceback

Answer (score 0):

It seems the libraries you are using do not support Django 1.7 yet.